# Derivation of influence function in Understanding Black-box Predictions via Influence Functions paper

Tags: machine-learning

In [Understanding Black-box Predictions via Influence Functions paper Appendix A](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.04730.pdf), the authors provide a standard derivation for influence functions, however, I could not understand one of the steps. They mentioned that from the step $(12)$

$$\Delta_{\epsilon} \approx -[\nabla^2R(\hat{\theta}) + \epsilon\nabla^2L(z, \hat{\theta})]^{-1}[\nabla R(\hat{\theta}) + \epsilon\nabla L(z, \hat{\theta})]$$

to step $(13)$

$$
\Delta_\epsilon \approx -\nabla^2R(\hat{\theta})\nabla L(z, \hat{\theta})\epsilon
$$

by dropping $o(\epsilon)$ terms. Also, we have that $\nabla R(\hat{\theta}) = 0$. Therefore, I could not get what it meant when they mentioned dropping $o(\epsilon)$ terms.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.